# Why can't I lower the item size in memcached (anymore)?

Tags: memcached

I'm running `memcached` and recently upgraded to the latest Debian release. I'm not sure what version of memcached I had before, but the new one doesn't like this configuration setting I had in the past:

```
-I 1K
```

I want to limit the item size to 1 kilobyte, but now `memcached` is telling me:

```
$ memcached -m 64 -p 11213 -l 127.0.0.1 -U 0 -I 1K
slab_chunk_max (bytes: 1048576) cannot be larger than -I (item_size_max 1024)
```

It seems that the slab size can be set to a *larger* value, but nothing smaller than 1 megabyte.

I've looked at the manual page, etc. and I can't see any option which looks like it might let me *reduce* this value below 1 megabyte.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I had to use lower case to make this work otherwise it would crash.

```
Use: -I 5m

Not: -I 5M
```

Hopefully this will help someone else with a similar issue.

Comment: I think the default max item size is already 1MiB (regardless of the CaSe used), so setting it higher isn't the problem. I'd like to set the value to something *lower* than 1MiB (in my case, 1KiB). `1M` versus `1m` doesn't make a difference in my case (they both work). Also, when specifying a raw value in bytes, `1024` (1KiB) yields the same error reported above.